# Internal server Error when refreshing the page when offline and fetch API

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, offline, progressive-web-apps, next.js

I've been having some difficulty getting the plugin to work well in a next-offline example project.
I would greatly appreciate a support from you

**Expected Behavior**

When refreshing the page while offline it should work even if it has not been previously refreshed when connected to the internet.

**Current Behavior**
By navigating to a page that was not previously refreshed while online. When switching to offline mode and refreshing the page this results in internal server error because the server tries to fetch the API. On the client side, without refresh it works well.

**Steps to Reproduce**
**ONLINE**

- Navigate to PAGE 1
- Navigate to PAGE 2 (fetch https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 using isomorphic-unfetch)
- Return to PAGE 1

**OFFLINE**

- Navigate to PAGE 2
- Refresh the page

Link to project example: [next-offline example project](https://github.com/ivanarielcaceres/next-offline-example/tree/master/examples/now1)

Comment: Do you have a link where this site is running that we could try? It may help us to help you. Also, this site passes the Chrome Lighthouse tests for PWA?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response! 

The final site is running on: https://atacadogames.tk/

But also testing with the basic example of next-offline (https://github.com/ivanarielcaceres/next-offline-example/tree/master/examples/now1) and also with the example of next, with-sw-precache (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sw-precache) using the plugin sw-precache-webpack gives the same problem.

Comment: Running the Chrome Lighthouse tests against https://atacadogames.tk/ gives some PWA errors. You probably want to try and fix those.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Mathias for the recommendation. But the examples provided from next-offline and with-sw-precache oficial repository does'nt work as expected. When the client navigate from page 1 to page 2 (api fetch on getInitialProps) works fine, but when realodign the page (f5) Nexts tries to fetch the API from server side, and thats the main problem.  The app falling into internal server error.